# Angular use marquee tag in ng-html-bind

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I have a information text area and it is represented in marquee right to left. But I also update text every 45 second and i want to restart the motion of marquee

How can i restart the moving of text when the text changed? I use angular ng-html-bind for update the text in every 45 seconds

My controller code is below;

`$scope.bind = "<p><font size=\"6\"><marquee>Hello</marquee></font></p>";`

Html code;

```
<div ng-bind-html="bind">
```

Comment: Marquee it's not an official w3c tag. Avoid it and use a dedicated js. However if you want to mantain this tag you have to cheat the page. When you refresh your test make a copy of whole <P>, remove actual one, add then the copy with new text so the marquee will start from position 0. This appears ugly because the real solution it's to avoid marquee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to bind the html, I would recommend just binding the text.

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/yaloyo/4/edit?html,js,output)

If you do want to bind new html, you can use [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) to mark the html as safe and remove the escape character \ from your html string:

```
$scope.myHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml('<p><font size="6"><marquee>Hello</marquee></font></p>');
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/xetove/6/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: my problem isn't binding. I can bind text every 45 sec. but i want to restart the position of text. In your example is also like my code, text change ok but it continue where it change. what can i do for restart the position when text change?

Comment: My second JSBIN will restart the position of the text. It loads a new marquee element.

Comment: yes it works but i still have problem because i call webservice every 45 second and i update the text with new data timeout isn't work for me i think :(

Comment: $timeout is not related to the problem. When you get the response from your webservice you can use $sce to assign the new html to your $scope.bind variable. I have updated the second JSBIN to use interval with updates every 4 seconds. To see an example with 45 second updates, you can change 4000 to 45000.

Comment: yes, you are right my problem wasnt about timeout. It is work thank you so much bro!